# How to use special characters and colours in error messages in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings

I am writting a package in R, and I come around the warnings and error messages. In the book https://style.tidyverse.org/error-messages.html the use of ℹ and ✖ is adviced. However, it doesn't mention how to use the different special character.

On top of that, I would like to know how to colour different elements of the messages provided, such as when loading tidyverse.

[image: Output with coloured parts]

Thanks

Comment: I think these colored messages use the `crayon` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vctrs` package is using `rlang::format_error_bullets`

```
cat(rlang::format_error_bullets(c(i = "Info", x = "Bad")))
#> ℹ Info
#> x Bad
```

This function is using `cli::symbol$info` and `cli::symbol$cross` which are ultimately just `"ℹ"` and `"x"`

`tidyverse:::tidyverse_attach` uses `crayon` for colours.

```
cat(paste0(crayon::bold("Attaching packages\n"), crayon::green("Green Text")))
```

[image: colours]